# Python - Stream archive to remote

Tags: python

So my problem is that I need to stream lots of files that can potentially be very large to a remote host without creating a new file.
Standard solution: In go I'd use streams to write new files to a tar archive, they'd be compressed and sent over network to my remote. Easy to achieve in go, but my requirement is, that it needs to be standard python with no additional libraries (don't ask....).
I've found tarfile and an option to send data over network. Both work, but I don't see how I can use tarfile or anything else from the python standard library to plugin together as streams for low memory footprint.

Can you point me in a direction? I'm sure I'm missing something, this can't be too hard...

Comment: I didn't understand what prevents you from using both tarfile and the option to send data over the network when you've found that both do what you expect.

Comment: tarfile only writes to files, not to the network. In Go I can stream the tar(gz(data)) directly to the network. In python I didn't find an option to do that. Only via an external fifo which would be really ugly to do...

Comment: The python stdlib has `Socket`.  There may be a higher level solution, but you can definitely send arbitrary data with a socket...

Comment: I know about socket, but is it possible to create a tar gz archive and stream the data put into the archive directly to a remote server?
Basically:
for each file in directory:
  archive.addfile(file)

and archive should not just grow and consume memory but be sent out to a remote server.